# Can the equivalence between principle bundles and maps to classifying spaces be turned into an adjunction.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, higher-category-theory

We have that $G-PBun(X)$, the category of topological principal bundles for a structure group $G$ is equivalent to  $Top[X,BG]$ where $BG$ is the classifying space of $G$.

This almost looks like an adjunction - can it be turned into one?

Maybe in a higher-dimensional sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want _adjunction between what what and what_? If you're talking about categories $Bun_G(X)$ and $[X,BG]$ — sure, any equivalence of categories can be refined to an adjoint equivalence.

Comment: I am talking about those two categories. But I can't see how to turn $Bun_G(X)$ into a hom-space between $FX$ and $B$ in some category, for some functor $F$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an adjunction, but rather the statement that the $2$-functor which sends a (nice) space $X$ to its groupoid of principal $G$-bundles is [representable](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/representable+functor), namely by $BG$. Actually this is the functorial definition of $BG$.

Answer (score 6):

There is no left adjoint of $B$ as far as I know, which seems like what youre asking for, but there is in fact a right adjoint. Let $\Omega$ denote the loop space functor sending a space $S$ to the space of based loops in $S$. Then $\Omega$ is a functor to topological monoids where based loops are composed in the obvious way and we have a natural isomorphism

$$
\operatorname{Hom}(BG, X) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G,\Omega X)
$$

where the left $\operatorname{Hom}$ is as pointed topological spaces and the right $\operatorname{Hom}$ is as topological monoids.

This no longer classifies principal $G$-bundles since were looking at maps *out of* $BG$ but it is an adjunction of the $B$ functor.

For a reference, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128883/why-omega-x-and-bg-are-adjoint-functors).